How do I make div elements of the same size?
I have the following piece of code, I am trying to achive a situation where I have 4 boxes with some statistics with a see more statistics button, when pressed, the remaining statistical boxes should appear below, I have achieved this but the boxes appearing after clicking the mentioned button are not the same size as the 4 top boxes, any quick fix for this?:
@model ComplaintMngSys.Models.DashboardViewModel.DashboardDataViewModel

<div class="row">
    <!-- Total Investigations -->
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-6">
        <div class="small-box bg-blue">
            <div class="inner">
                <h3>@Model.DashboardSummaryViewModel.TotalInvestigations</h3>
                <p>Total Investigations</p>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
                <i class="ion ion-pie-graph"></i>
            </div>
            <a href="@Url.Action("AllInvestigations", "ComplaintManage")" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Investigation Resolved -->
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-6">
        <div class="small-box bg-green">
            <div class="inner">
                <h3>@Model.DashboardSummaryViewModel.TotalInvestigationResolved</h3>
                <p>Investigations Resolved</p>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
                <i class="ion ion-stats-bars"></i>
            </div>
            <a href="@Url.Action("ResolvedInvestigations", "ComplaintManage")" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Investigation Referred to LEAS -->
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-6">
        <div class="small-box bg-yellow">
            <div class="inner">
                <h3>@Model.DashboardSummaryViewModel.TotalReferredInvestigation</h3>
                <p>Investigations Referred to LEAS</p>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
                <i class="ion ion-stats-bars"></i>
            </div>
            <a href="@Url.Action("ReferredInvestigations", "ComplaintManage")" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Investigation Unresolved -->
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-6">
        <div class="small-box bg-red">
            <div class="inner">
                <h3>@(Model.DashboardSummaryViewModel.TotalUser - Model.DashboardSummaryViewModel.ActiveComplaints)</h3>
                <p>Investigations Unresolved</p>
            </div>
            <div class="icon">
                <i class="ion ion-stats-bars"></i>
            </div>
            <a href="@Url.Action("UnResolvedInvestigations", "ComplaintManage")" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- See More Statistics Button -->
    <div class="col-12 text-center">
        <button id="seeMoreBtn" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="toggleStatistics()">See More Statistics</button>
    </div>

    <!-- Additional Statistics -->
    <div id="additionalStatistics" class="row" style="display: none;">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-6">
            <div class="small-box bg-blue">
                <div class="inner">
                    <h3>@Model.InvestigationEnforcementLitigationData.TotalDELs</h3>
                    <p>Total Enforcements</p>
                </div>
                <div class="icon">
                    <i class="ion ion-pie-graph"></i>
                </div>
                <a href="@Url.Action("IndexAllInvestigation", "ComplaintManage")" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-6">
            <div class="small-box bg-green">
                <div class="inner">
                    <h3>@Model.InvestigationEnforcementLitigationData.EnforcementTotal</h3>
                    <p>Total Litigations</p>
                </div>
                <div class="icon">
                    <i class="ion ion-stats-bars"></i>
                </div>
                <a href="@Url.Action("IndexAllInvestigation", "ComplaintManage")" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Add New Investigation -->
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-6">
        <a href="#" onclick="AddEdit(-1)" class="info-box">
            <span class="info-box-icon bg-warning elevation-1"><i class="fas fa-plug"></i></span>
            <div class="info-box-content">
                <span class="info-box-text">Add New Investigation</span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function toggleStatistics() {
        var additionalStats = document.getElementById('additionalStatistics');
        if (additionalStats.style.display === 'none') {
            additionalStats.style.display = 'flex';
            document.getElementById('seeMoreBtn').innerText = 'See Less Statistics';
        } else {
            additionalStats.style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('seeMoreBtn').innerText = 'See More Statistics';
        }
    }
</script>

I have tried the code above but it does not seem to do the job.

Lookup css grid.

I copy your code remove you variate run in my project like this:

You can give the tag <h3> styles. If your content more of them is 3 lines ,you can give it the height of 3 lines , If it beyond  3 lines,you take the first 3 lines and put an ellipsis after them. Add a title attribute to the <h3> tag  so you can see the full content when you move your mouse in.
Set tile :
<div class="col-lg-3 col-6">
     <div class="small-box bg-red">
         <div class="inner">
             <h3 title="(Model.DashboardSummaryViewModel.TotalUser-Model.DashboardSummaryViewModel.ActiveComplaints)">
                 (Model.DashboardSummaryViewModel.TotalUser
                 - Model.DashboardSummaryViewModel.ActiveComplaints)</h3>
             <p>Investigations Unresolved</p>
         </div>
         <div class="icon">
             <i class="ion ion-stats-bars"></i>
         </div>
         <a href="@Url.Action("UnResolvedInvestigations", "ComplaintManage")" class="small-box-footer">More info <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></a>
     </div>
</div>

Set styles:
<style>
     .small-box{
     word-break:break-all;
    }
    
    .small-box .inner h3{
        -webkit-line-clamp: 3; /* show lines */
        overflow: hidden;
        display: -webkit-box;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        height:108px;/* 3 lines height */
    }
        
</style>

The result is :

